# retrieve parent content from a context

Tags: go, go-gin

I am created a new context form gin context.
something like this .

```
newCtx:= context.WithValue(ginCtx, key, value )
```

ginCtx is of type *gin.Context.

Now from the newCtx , I would like to retrieve ginCtx again so that I can use all the method associated with *gin.Context .

How do I do that ?

If I can't , then what is the use of WithValue() function ?

New to golang  & gin . Help appreciated.

Comment: "How do I do that?" You can't, because that's not part of [the interface](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#Context).

Comment: You can use the key and value parameters to store ginCtx with a certain key, and retrieve it with newCtx.Value

Answer (score 1):

As noted by others, [`context.Context`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#Context) does not provide the means to access the parent context.

But in case of [`gin.Context`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context) you don't need to. First, `gin.Context` implements `context.Context`, so whenever a `context.Context` is required, you may pass your gin context.

Also, `gin.Context` has a [`Context.Set()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Set) method which you can use to add a new key-value pair to the context. So you don't need to create a new context, you can just do:

```
ginCtx.Set(key, value)
```

Do note however that while creating a new `context.Context` with [`context.WithValue()`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#WithValue) creates a *new* context and only that will contain the passed key-value pair, and the original context will not (`context.Context` is *immutable*). On the other side the gin context's `Set()` method adds the key-value pair to the context it's called on, and it does not create a new context. So they are not equivalent.

Comment: Thanks , for the answer . One question here , if we can't retrieve the parent context , then what is the use of WithContext ?

Comment: @Prasenjit What `WithContext` are you referring to? [`Request.WithContext()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.WithContext)?

Comment: Sorry , I was trying to ask , what is the use of the function WithValue() if we can't retrieve the parent context ?

Comment: @Prasenjit It's use is that it creates a new context that will contain the provided key-value pair. Without that call, the context will not. That's its use. By itself it has no use, only if you use / pass the new context to other functions / subtasks.